# composer issue installing symfony fosuserbundle

Tags: symfony, installation, fosuserbundle

I have facing some troubles to install `FosUserBundle` in Symfony 2.8. I haven't had this problem before in others projects.

I have tried:

- `composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2.0"`
- `php composer.phar update friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` with  `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"` in the required section of `composer.json`.

With both options I get this error:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\MiAplicacion>composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle "~2 .0" ./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove twig/twig v1.23.1
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.3.2
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.23.1
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.0.0 requires twig/twig ^1.28 || ^2.0 -> sa tisfiable by twig/twig[v1.28.0, v1.28.1, v1.28.2, v1.29.0, v1.30.0, v1.31.0, v1.
32.0, v1.33.0, v1.33.1, v1.33.2, v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2] .
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.28.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.28.1, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.28.2, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.29.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.30.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.31.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.32.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.33.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.33.1, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.33.2, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.0.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.1.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.2.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.3.0, v1.23.1].
    - Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.3.1, v1.23.1].
    - Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v1.23.1) -> satisfiable by t wig/twig[v1.23.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

My required in `composer.json` is (*I added the last row from the original symfony project*):

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"
    },
```

Can I fix the composer issue?

If not, there is any way to install `FosUserBundle` downloading it manually and copying it in my project?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you have upgraded to Symfony 2.8 manually or with a fresh installation but as composer shows, to install `"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0"` you should have at minimum `twig ^1.28` so I think you should resolve this problem adding the line `"twig/twig": "~1.28|~2.0"` to the composer `require` section to force the upgrade.

If the error comes again with this message part `Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v1.23.1)` you should take a look (*one by one*) at which package block the upgrade. At a first look seems nothing wrong in your `composer.json`.